# R plot frequency distribution

Tags: r

How can I plot a frequency distribution in R? I don't want to bin values. I just want to plot frequency for each value. The `hist` function insists on binning values unless I specify bins manually (really tedious, because I don't know the values in advance).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could `plot` the `table` of your data:

```
xx<-sample(1:10,100,replace=TRUE)
plot(table(xx))
```

[image: a histogram]

Answer (score 1):

have you tried s.distri {ade4}? http://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/ade4/ade4-html/s.distri.html

```
 library(ade4)
  xy <- cbind.data.frame(x = runif(200,-1,1), y = runif(200,-1,1))
  distri <- data.frame(w1 = rpois(200, xy$x * (xy$x > 0)))
  s.value(xy, distri$w1, cpoi = 1)
```

Comment: This wasn't what I meant, but it looks fun.

Answer (score 1):

```
table(sample(1:10,20,replace=T))
```